# How to make a custom Number class convertible to int & float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I have implemented a number class in python 3. What do I need to do so that

```
float(mynumber)
```

works correctly?

Comment: What version of Python?  2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Python 3. (I'm adding this to the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs, [Emulating Numeric Types](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types):

```
object.__complex__(self) 
object.__int__(self) 
object.__long__(self) 
object.__float__(self) 

Called to implement the built-in functions complex(), int(), long(), and float(). 
Should return a value of the appropriate type.
```

Comment: Thanks, where in the docs did you find this? I did spend some time looking for it.

Comment: @erik And hex() and oct() and bin() etc... as link I posted below

Comment: I added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `__float__` or `__int__` or whatever you want...

It's also worth noting that using an `abc` or the `numbers` module could be useful to end users...